# How to generate a list in Scala, where each item depends on the preceding item

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming

Say, I have a recursive rule:

```
f(0) = 2
f(n) = f(n-1) * 3 - 2
```

I need to generate a list for n ∈ [0, 10].

If I was interested in f(10), I could use `foldLeft` like this:

```
(1 to 10).foldLeft(2)((z, _) => z * 3 - 2)
```

I want to achieve the following in a concise and functional style:

```
val list = new ListBuffer[Int]
list += 2
(1 to 10).foreach {
    list += list.last * 3 - 2
}
```

What's the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the multiple approaches involves for instance the use of `scanLeft` as follows,

```
(1 to 10).scanLeft(2)( (acc,_) => acc*3-2)
```

This applies the function onto the latest (accumulated) result.

**Update**

Also consider this `Iterator`

```
val f = Iterator.iterate(2)(_*3-2)
```

and so

```
(1 to 10).map(_ => f.next)
```

For a large number of iterations, initial value `2: Int` may be cast onto `BigInt(2)` so as to avoid overflow for instance in

```
(1 to 100).map(_ => f.next)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `Stream` to generate this list lazily and functionally:

```
  val stream: Stream[Int] = {
    def next(i: Int): Stream[Int] = {
      val n = i * 3 - 2
      n #:: next(n)
    }
    2 #:: next(2)
  }

  println(stream.take(11).toList)
  //prints List(2, 4, 10, 28, 82, 244, 730, 2188, 6562, 19684, 59050)
```

Comment: This solution requires O(n^2) time and O(n) stack depth to generate a list of size n, doesn't it? So generating a list of 100K items won't work with this solution.

Comment: @DavidFrank No, this uses lazy evaluation.  The stack depth is constant and the time is linear.